# how to fix the issue with getting sedoparking.com/ \ Gogolebot html in crul and guzzle request in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, laravel-7

in laravel 7 in one of my jobs I send a http request and for 95 percent of them I get html response.

**Request**

```
$url = "some url";
/**
 * Request with Guzzle and xml
 */
$response = Http::retry(3, 1000)->timeout(60)->withHeaders([
    'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.65.3',
    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
])->withOptions([
    'referer' => true,
    'verify' => false
])->get($url);
if($response->successful()){
    try {
        self::$response = $response->body();
        return true;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Log::error(
            'status:' . $response->status() .'\n' .
            'server Error:' . $response->serverError() .'\n' .
            'client Error:' . $response->clientError() .'\n' .
            'body:' . $response->body()
        );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}else{
    try {
        Log::error($url);
        Log::error(
            'status:' . $response->status() .'\n' .
            'server Error:' . $response->serverError() .'\n' .
            'client Error:' . $response->clientError() .'\n' .
            'body:' . $response->body()
        );
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Log::error("couldn't even log the error of guzzle request");
        Log::error($th);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Response**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #partner, iframe {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            background: transparent;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <meta content="NOW" name="expires">
    <meta content="index, follow, all" name="GOOGLEBOT">
    <meta content="index, follow, all" name="robots">
    <!-- Following Meta-Tag fixes scaling-issues on mobile devices -->
    <meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;
            user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

<div id="partner"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getParam() {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == 'domain') {
                return pair[1];
            }
        }
        return  window.location.host;
    }
    ;

    document.write(
            '<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"'
                    + 'src="//sedoparking.com/frmpark/'
                    + getParam() + '/'
                    + 'sedopark'
                    + '/park.js">'
                    + '<\/script>'
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Things I did

- asked the supplier to check if their server have any protection against our requests. they don't and all the other type of request we send (purchase and contact etc) they have no issue.
- updated our php to 7.3 on all of our domains and subdomains
- at first it was curl I changed it to HTTP still have the same issue.
- I've added 'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.65.3' AND 'verify' => false based on different searches on interent. but none of them fixed the issue.
- in the guzzle > src > handler > crulfactory.php changed the verify to always be zero

```
if ($options['verify'] === false) {
    unset($conf[CURLOPT_CAINFO]);
    $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
    $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
} else {
    // $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
    // $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
    $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
    $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

#### Extra information

This job is send regulary (20 jobs at the same time) every 30 minutes

as per logs, it shows that the http request has returned a resposnse successfully. but when I log the response the html is what I get. I should get XML of what supplier sends me.

Comment: What do you get when this fails?  Do the log files show any information?

Comment: @NigelRen as per logs, it shows that the http request has returned a resposnse successfully. but when I log the response the html is what I get. I should get XML of what supplier sends me.